# GIT move files from folder to subfolder

Tags: files, git, move

I have the following folder structure.

```
Service
|
-- App1
  |
  --- bin
  |
  --- file1
  |
  --- file2
|
--App2
  |
  --- bin
  |
  --- file1
  |
  --- file2
  |
  --- file3
|
--App3
  |
  --- bin
  |
  --- file1
  |
  --- file2
```

I'm looking to move files only from the root of App folders to their corresponding bin folders whilst preserving GIT history. So the end result should be:

```
Service
|
-- App1
  |
  --- bin
     |
      --- file1
     |
      --- file2
|
--App2
  |
  --- bin
     |
      --- file1
     |
      --- file2
     |
      --- file3
|
--App3
  |
  --- bin
     |
      --- file1
     |
      --- file2
```

I attempted the following...

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="/c/Service"

subs=`ls $dir1`

for i in $subs; do
  git mv $dir1/$i/* $dir1/$i/bin/
done
```

...but see the following errors:

*fatal: can not move directory into itself*

*fatal: Invalid path '/c': No such file or directory*

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Path `/c:`? What operating system are you using?

Comment: So your command runs "git mv /c/Service/App1/* /c/Service/App1/bin" and the "*" will include "bin". You need to get rid of the bin. You could do the move in 2 steps, move first into ElEpHaNt or another name that doesn't exist and then move that to bin. What do you want to do with things already in "bin"?

Comment: The operating system is Windows where I have Git for Windows installed. The "bin" folder is empty for all Apps.

Answer (score 0):

From the parent of the `Service` directory, you can do:

```
$ for file in Service/*/*; do 
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then 
        echo mv "$file" "$(dirname -- "$file")/bin"
    fi
 done
mv Service/App1/file1 Service/App1/bin
mv Service/App1/file2 Service/App1/bin
mv Service/App2/file1 Service/App2/bin
mv Service/App2/file2 Service/App2/bin
mv Service/App2/file3 Service/App2/bin
mv Service/App3/file1 Service/App3/bin
mv Service/App3/file2 Service/App3/bin
```

If that looks correct, remove the `echo` and run it again to actually move the files.

Note that the approach above will *preserve* git history, as requested. If you don't want to preserve it but instead you want to add these commands to git's history, simply use `git mv` instead of `mv`:

```
for file in Service/*/*; do 
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then 
        echo git mv "$file" "$(dirname -- "$file")/bin"
    fi
 done
```

Comment: This won't preserve git history

Comment: @cryptarch why? I think I haven't understood what is meant by preserving git history. Isn't the history stored in the `.git` directory? Why would this affect it one way or another?

Comment: The code you've provided merely uses mv, which doesn't register the change in filename with git. That means when checking the git history of the new file, it will be truncated; changes done to the old file won't be associated with the new file. At minimum, the `mv` command should be prefixed with git (i.e. `echo git mv "$file" ...`, and at the end of the forloop there should be a git commit to record the change.

Comment: @cryptarch yes, exactly, since it doesn't use git, it will not affect git history and, therefore, will preserve it. If we do it your way, we don't preserve the history, we're changing it. If the OP meant what you are suggesting, then that really should be clarified in the question since "preserve" means "do not change". But I added a version that doesn't preserve the history and instead changes it as suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. It seemed pretty clear to me that the user meant the history of the file should be preserved after the mv. From the point of view of Git, your way merely introduces some uncommitted deletions and additions. I can add a separate answer and we can let the OP decide which they prefer, but it seemed like overkill if you would agree to make the answer more consistent with a typical Git workflow.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I see you added an edit to give OP the option for which they prefer. Okay, I'll remove the -1 :)

Comment: Yeah, I mean, frankly your approach makes more sense to me it just isn't how I understood the concept of "preserving" but then I'm a language geek and a pedant so it's probably me :)